# Drawing in OpenGL using triangle strips or quad strips

Tags: c++, opengl

I have exported a .obj file and I have parsed the information inside into vectors of verticies, uvs and normals (C++). How do I draw this data in OpenGL. Note that I am running an old version of OpenGL and am forced to use Triangle strips and Quad strips. The code below shows what I have so far.

```
OpenGLObject::OpenGLObject(std::string& fileName) {
    std::ifstream inFile(fileName.c_str());
    if (!inFile.is_open()) {
        std::string err = "[Error] Unable to open file " + fileName + ".";
        throw(err);
    }

    std::vector<unsigned int> vertexIndices, uvIndices, normalIndices;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
    std::vector<glm::vec2> uvs;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> normals;
    // Reading file contents
    while (inFile.good()) {
        std::string token;
        inFile >> token;

        // Parsing verticies
        if (token == "v") {
            glm::vec3 tempVect;
            inFile >> tempVect.x;
            inFile >> tempVect.y;
            inFile >> tempVect.z;
            vertices.push_back(tempVect);
        }
        // Parsing uvs
        else if (token == "vt") {
            glm::vec2 tempUv;
            inFile >> tempUv.x;
            inFile >> tempUv.y;
            uvs.push_back(tempUv);
        }
        // Parsing normals
        else if (token == "vn") {
            glm::vec3 tempNormal;
            inFile >> tempNormal.x;
            inFile >> tempNormal.y;
            inFile >> tempNormal.z;
            normals.push_back(tempNormal);
        }
        // Parsing faces (Note: not robust for all .obj files)
        else if (token == "f") {
            unsigned int vertexIndex[4], uvIndex[4], normalIndex[4];
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                inFile >> vertexIndex[i];
                vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[i]);
                inFile.ignore(1, '/');
                inFile >> uvIndex[i];
                uvIndices.push_back(uvIndex[i]);
                inFile.ignore(1, '/');
                inFile >> normalIndex[i];
                normalIndices.push_back(normalIndex[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    inFile.close();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vertexIndices.size(); ++i) {
        unsigned int vertexIndex = vertexIndices[i];
        glm::vec3 vertex = vertices[vertexIndex - 1];
        vertices_.push_back(vertex);
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < uvIndices.size(); ++i) {
        unsigned int uvIndex = uvIndices[i];
        glm::vec2 uv = uvs[uvIndex - 1];
        uvs_.push_back(uv);
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < normalIndices.size(); ++i) {
        unsigned int normalIndex = normalIndices[i];
        glm::vec3 normal = normals[normalIndex - 1];
        normals_.push_back(normal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Actually in older versions of OpenGL use have a greater set of primitives to choose from than in modern OpenGL. So I really don't see your problem. Why not simply draw using simple (indexed) triangles. You're not limited to the `…_STRIP` primitives. `GL_TRIANGLES` (and `GL_QUADS`!) are actually available in OpenGL-2.1 and earlier.

Comment: I am really new to OpenGL; can you give me an example given verticies and indicies? I know how to simple shapes like cubes using just verticies but I do not understand how the indicies and verticies can be used to draw more complicated objects.